# SSRS schedule failure intimation

Tags: ssrs

I am scheduling a report using SQL Server Reporting Services Subscription option.
Suppose my rdl file is corrupted or my stored procedure has got some problem.
Then the report won’t generate in its next turn. 
What can I have to get the intimation that the report does not generated properly?

Can I configure to get a mail on report generation failure

Answer (score 2):

SSRS report subscriptions generate job entries in SQL Agent.  Find the corresponding agent job and set email alerts through it's properties for failure.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - while exploring my own similar question [alert when any job in a job category fails](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18153/alert-when-any-job-in-a-job-category-fails/18155#18155), I uncovered that while it is true that SSRS report subscriptions generate job entries in SQL Agent, the failure of an SSRS report subscription **does not** fail the SQL job.

You can find the failure in `ExecutionLogStorage.Status` in the`ReportServer` database.

Comment: That is interesting.  Is that expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure - in some ways it makes sense since the Agent did its job and it is usually some SSRS thing that is broken...

Comment: Yeah, I see that point too.  Just interesting.  I would love to here the argument from both sides, purely for academic reasons.